# Eclipse - Method Call Feed?

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse is there a way to view all methods that are called while a program is debugging in a list-style view? I'm not looking to step through the code and I'm aware of the call hierarchy, I'd just like to see every method that is involved while running a process on an application - something like a feed of all activity. Anything like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing as such out of the box eclipse provides except Call Hierarchy which you already know. For following options you have to code a bit:

> 1. Use logging framework (log4j, slf4j etc.) to put trace in each method and it will log all methods in sequence at runtime
> 2. If you are using spring you can achieve above result with the help of aspects as well
> 3. You can use byte code modifier like javaassist to insert these logging statements at runtime as well.

All these options only work with a good logging. Hope this helps.